# Web Deployment on IIS7 Issues

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, deployment

I've been at this all day, trying to get Web Deployment setup on my server. First off, I'm running IIS7 under Windows Server 2008 Data Center 64bit (on a VPS). At first I thought I had it working, but it seems I was using the old (Windows Administrator login only) IIS6 stuff that comes alongside IIS7.

I've followed this guide perfectly, and I'm still getting errors: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/.

This is the error I receive (as per the directions at the end of the article):

[image]

Any help is appreciated. I've tried everything (I've verified all the basic things like LOCAL SERVICE folder access, IIS Manager permissions, the service is active, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you would see if you try to connect to a web server where the remote management service is disabled.

From an elevated command prompt, type: **net start wmsvc**

You can also accomplish this from the Services Console, go to **Administrative Tools -> Services** and find the service **Web Management Service** and make sure it is started

Hope this helps